# Rails: how to redirect to a url (as a query string param) with query string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redirect, query-string

Say id = 1, redirect_url = www.example.com?a=1&b=2&c=3
And I want to append these two to a path `/index`

And when I perform a get request to index, I would want to perform some checks and ultimately redirect to the redirect_url.

However, a problem with this is the appended path is :`/index?id=1&redirect_url=www.example.com?a=1&b=2&c=3`

And there is no way for Rails to tell if a, b, c is a query string of the redirect_url.

Is there any smart way to do it so that a,b,c automatically becomes the query string of the redirect_url?

Comment: Please explain better

Answer (score 1):

If a, b and c are query string params and Id is URL id, you can pass like this

```
example_path(your_id, :a => params[:a], :b => params[:b], :c => params[:c])
```

becomes

```
/example/your_id?a=1&b=2&c=3
```